# What word should I use when I want to call a parameter "this" but can't?

Tags: javascript

I'm sure similar questions have been asked before, but I don't know how to search for it.

I want to run several functions inside an event handler, but I also want to use "this" inside those functions, but I can't, so I want to pass "this" as an argument to those functions. I also want to literally write "this" inside those functions, but again I can't, because it's an illegal parameter.

In the following simplipied example, I used "tthis" instead.

```
masthead = document.getElementById('masthead');
masthead.addEventListener('click', function() {
  changeColor(this);
  changeFont(this);
  changeSize(this);
});

function changeColor(tthis) {
  tthis.style.cssText = 'color: red';
}

function changeFont(tthis) {
  tthis.style.cssText = 'font-family: Arial';
}

function changeSize(tthis) {
  tthis.style.cssText = 'font-size: 5em';
}
```

My question is, what's the word I should use in place of "tthis" in such situation? "that"? "object"? "target"? "eventTarget"? Does any style guide cover this? I tried to search Airbnb but Ctrl-F "this" turns out a bad idea.

Comment: It's really an opinionated discussion so off topic for Stack Overflow, but afaik _this and that are most commonly uswd

Comment: Well, since they are elements, you could use `element`, `elmt`, `ele`, or some variation thereof. That's probably more descriptive than just `this`. But of course there's always the tried and true `self`.

Comment: How about `self`?

Comment: Stackoverflow tells me my question is "on hold" because it's opinion based, and suggested me edit the question. Now I have edited the question, is there a way to request remove the hold?

Answer (score 3):

Look at each function in isolation and name the parameter after what you expect it to be. In this case, I would use `element`.